# Java Crash on JAVA 8 SIGSEGV (0xb)

Tags: java, java-8, crash

I have a java program that continues to crash.
Here how I run the java

```
/opt/ejre/bin/java -Xcheck:jni -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java/java_error.log -jar /opt/ecube/server/ecube_2.jar -cp /opt/ecube/server/ecube_2_lib
```

Here link to one of the java log error hs_err*.log

Beyond the java crash, another problem is that on some PC it never crashes (the same program runs since 1 year without crashes) and in other ones does.
All the PCs have the same HW spec and all of them are flashed with the same .img .

Can someone help me?

Thanks

EDIT: the old link seem to be broken. Here the new one.
https://gofile.io/?c=87JZR2

Comment: The link returns 404.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: It still returns 404, please add a valid link to the debug file or paste the relevant parts showing the error and the context.

Comment: It looks like you're using mixed architecture. I mean Java 64 bit and your JNI code was compiled to 32 bit or vice versa. If I'm right you'll have to use the same architecture-based code.

Comment: Is not Java crosses between 32 and 64 bit without any recompile?

Comment: It's hard to understand but as I saw  your Java version is 32bit. You can intsall that shared object with compiled for 32 bit architecture. Finally I think you don't have to recompile your code.

Comment: Googling it I find that Java does cross-compile all your classes and imported library but NOT the native library. I will try to replace these libraries.